# c udp non-blocking socket with recvfrom and select

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I want to implement at the client side non-blocking socket with select function. But it doesn't work as expected. In the code below it never runs into else , rv is always 1 and when nothing is on the socket application stops for a while and continue when another messages is on the socket. I don't want that behavior , I want that client sends back message to the server when there is nothing on the socket to recvfrom.

```
fd_set readfds; 

fcntl(sd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); 


while (1) {

        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(sd, &readfds);

        rv = select(sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL); 

        if(rv == 1){ 

            nbytes = recvfrom(sd, buf, RW_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &srv_addr, &addrlen); 


        } else {

            printf("I'm never here so I can't send message back to the server!\n");


        }

}
```

with struct timeval:

```
fd_set readfds; 
fcntl(sd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); 
struct timeval tv;


while (1) {

        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(sd, &readfds);

        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

        rv = select(sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv); 

        if(rv == 1){ 

            nbytes = recvfrom(sd, buf, RW_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &srv_addr, &addrlen); 


        } else {

            printf("I'm always here like now ! \n");


        }

}
```

Comment: Are you checking if `fcntl` call is successful and O_NONBLOCK is available in your system?

Comment: yes, I've checked if fcntl returns -1 and it doesn't, it returns 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the timeout (last parameter of select) to NULL, which means it will only return once data are available on the socket (or interrupt). You need to set a timeout it should wait. The timeout might be 0 if you don't want to wait, but 0 means to use a `struct timeval*` with `tv_sec=0` and `tv_usec=0` and not use a `struct timeval*` of NULL like you did.

Comment: I have changed the last parametar and set  &tv instead of NULL, where I previously set tv_sec=0 and tv_usec=0 but in this case select returns always 0, how can I know when I have something on the socket to read? Now it always goes into else it never receives from the server

Comment: Because you set the timeout to 0 (i.e. no wait) you end up in a kind of busy loop were you spend all the time printing that you got no data. You should eventually get from time to time `rv==1`, but because of your zero timeout 99.999% of all cases will be just nothing. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this design. Usually a setup with select and non-blocking is used to manage multiple sockets or to wait for data with a sensible (non-zero) timeout.

Comment: Server is sending packets to client with sequence numbers . I want at the client side to detect when packet is lost and which packet is lost using sequence numbers. But obviously when nothing is on the socket it doesn't mean that packet is lost. Do you have any idea how can I detect lost packets?

Comment: To know if a packet is lost you must know that there was a packet send. If the sender sends a packet each second you might assume that it is lost if you did not receive it after 2 seconds. If you don't know when a packet will be send you cannot detect its loss, only if you received a later packet (but packets might arrive in different order). You might have a look at the design of TCP which deals with all these problems.